# Hiding search field code only executes one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a piece of jQuery to make a search box appear when a user hovers over the search button, displays for five seconds, then disappears if the user hasn't given the search text field focus.

It currently just appears, disappears, then reappears for good. My code is below, you can see it in action at http://emilysenger.ca

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('input').blur(function(){
                jQuery('input').removeClass("focus");
        })
             .focus(function() {                
                 jQuery(this).addClass("focus")
        });

    jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#searchButton").hover(function(){
        jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function(e){
    jQuery(e).delay(5000, 
            function(e){
                if(!jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search").hasClass("focus"))
                    {
                        jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search").fadeOut("slow");
                    }

    });
    });

});
```

Some help with this would be *awesome*. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it so it fades out on the textbox's blur event too, and that it never fades out if the textbox has text in it. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DeEbG/).

The HTML:

```
<div id="sneakySearch">
    <form method="get" action="/">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchButton">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
function fadeOutSearch() {
    var element = jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search");
    if (!element.hasClass("focus") && element.val() == "") {
        element.fadeOut("slow");
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input').blur(function() {
        jQuery('input').removeClass("focus");
        setTimeout(fadeOutSearch, 1000);
    }).focus(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass("focus")
    });

    jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search").hide();
    jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#searchButton").hover(function() {
        jQuery("div#sneakySearch form input#search").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function(e) {
        setTimeout(fadeOutSearch, 1000);
    });
});
```